How to prevent MDX documents from automatically adding <p> tags when rendering text that includes line breaks inside existing <p> tags?
I noticed that when I add MDX documents to the Docusaurus blog, if I include a <p> tag with child elements and line breaks, the text content inside gets wrapped with an additional <p> tag.
Example:
             <section style={{textAlign: "justify", boxSizing: "border-box", visibility: "visible"}}>
              <p style={{whiteSpace: "normal", margin: "0px", padding: "0px", boxSizing: "border-box", visibility: "visible"}}>
               Recently,
               <span style={{color: "rgb(6, 82, 76)", visibility: "visible"}}>
                <strong style={{visibility: "visible"}}>
                 We
                </strong>
               </span>
               created a 
               <span style={{color: "rgb(6, 82, 76)", visibility: "visible"}}>
                <strong style={{visibility: "visible"}}>
                 new game
                </strong>
               </span>
               to play
              </p>
             </section>

It will be rendered as:
<section style="text-align: justify; box-sizing: border-box; visibility: visible;">
  <p style="white-space: normal; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; visibility: visible;">
    <p>Recently,</p>
    <span style="color: rgb(6, 82, 76); visibility: visible;">
      <strong style="visibility: visible;">
        <p>We</p>
      </strong>
    </span>
    <p>created a</p>
    <span style="color: rgb(6, 82, 76); visibility: visible;">
      <strong style="visibility: visible;">
       <p>new game</p>
      </strong>
    </span>
    <p>to play</p>
  </p>
</section>

This causes the paragraph, which should render on a single line, to be split into multiple lines due to the nested <p> tags.
I know I can edit the MDX manually to keep the text within the <p> tag on a single line, like this:
             <section style={{textAlign: "justify", boxSizing: "border-box", visibility: "visible"}}>
              <p style={{whiteSpace: "normal", margin: "0px", padding: "0px", boxSizing: "border-box", visibility: "visible"}}>Recently,<span style={{color: "rgb(6, 82, 76)", visibility: "visible"}}><strong style={{visibility: "visible"}}>We</strong></span>created a <span style={{color: "rgb(6, 82, 76)", visibility: "visible"}}><strong style={{visibility: "visible"}}>new game</strong></span>to play</p>
             </section>

Writing the content of the <p> tag on a single line prevents the automatic addition of nested <p> tags, allowing it to render correctly:
<section style="text-align: justify; box-sizing: border-box; visibility: visible;"><p style="white-space: normal; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; visibility: visible;">Recently,<span style="color: rgb(6, 82, 76); visibility: visible;"><strong style="visibility: visible;">We</strong></span>created a <span style="color: rgb(6, 82, 76); visibility: visible;"><strong style="visibility: visible;">new game</strong></span>to play</p></section>

The reason I haven't done this is that my entire MDX document is created by saving a webpage as a single MHTML file, then converting it to MDX using a Python script. I use BeautifulSoup4 for this process, and to improve the readability of the converted HTML, I call soup.prettify(), which formats each tag on a new line. This results in the extra <p> tags, as shown in my initial MDX code block. If I skip soup.prettify() and simply save str(soup), the HTML content in the MDX file is all on a single line, which makes it hard to read and maintain. I tried filtering out <p> tags in the script and merging their content onto a single line, but since the final step still requires converting soup to a string, I either end up with prettify() and lose the merging, or I keep everything on a single line, sacrificing readability.
My python script to merge <p> tags:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<section style="text-align: justify; box-sizing: border-box; visibility: visible;">
  <p style="white-space: normal; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; visibility: visible;">
    Recently,
    <span style="color: rgb(6, 82, 76); visibility: visible;">
      <strong style="visibility: visible;">
        We
      </strong>
    </span>
    created a
    <span style="color: rgb(6, 82, 76); visibility: visible;">
      <strong style="visibility: visible;">
        new game
      </strong>
    </span>
    to play
  </p>
</section>
"""

def merge_paragraph_tags(target_tag):
    result = ""

    for child in target_tag.children:
        if child.name:
            inner_html = merge_paragraph_tags(child)
            attrs_str = ''
            for attr in child.attrs:
                if isinstance(child[attr], list):
                    attrs_str += f"{attr}=\"{' '.join(child[attr])}\""
                else:
                    attrs_str += f'{attr}="{child[attr]}"'
            result += f"<{child.name} {attrs_str}>" + inner_html + f"</{child.name}>"
        else:
            result += child.strip()

    return result

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for p_tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    merged_content = merge_paragraph_tags(p_tag)

    # print(111, merged_content)

    p_tag.clear()
    p_tag.append(BeautifulSoup(merged_content, 'html.parser'))

# print(soup.prettify())
pretty_html = soup.prettify()
print(111, type(pretty_html))
print(str(soup))
print(soup.contents)
# print(''.join(soup.contents))


Is there a better solution, such as preventing MDX from automatically adding nested <p> tags?

MDX is JSX in markdown, and will typically result in HTML output. JSX, markdown, and HTML are all whitespace sensitive language with their own rules. MDX has to balance those. It’s also noteworthy that JSX is more similar to XML than to HTML. For example, JSX has self-closing elements, whereas HTML has void elements.
If the children of an MDX JSX element start on a new line, they are treated as markdown. Since Recently,  is a markdown paragraph in your example, that’s why you see it wrapped in an additional <p> element. You can opt-out of this behaviour by avoiding newlines:
<section style={{textAlign: "justify", boxSizing: "border-box", visibility: "visible"}}>
  <p
    style={{whiteSpace: "normal", margin: "0px", padding: "0px", boxSizing: "border-box", visibility: "visible"}}
  >Recently, <span 
    style={{color: "rgb(6, 82, 76)", visibility: "visible"}}> <strong
    style={{visibility: "visible"}}>We</strong> </span> 
  created a <span style={{color: "rgb(6, 82, 76)", visibility: "visible"}}>
  <strong style={{visibility: "visible"}}>new game</strong></span> to play</p>
</section>

Alternatively you can wrap the content in an MDX expression.
{
  <section style={{textAlign: "justify", boxSizing: "border-box", visibility: "visible"}}>
    <p style={{whiteSpace: "normal", margin: "0px", padding: "0px", boxSizing: "border-box", visibility: "visible"}}>
      {'Recently, '}
      <span style={{color: "rgb(6, 82, 76)", visibility: "visible"}}>
        <strong style={{visibility: "visible"}}>
          We
        </strong>
      </span>
      {' created a '}
      <span style={{color: "rgb(6, 82, 76)", visibility: "visible"}}>
        <strong style={{visibility: "visible"}}>
          new game
        </strong>
      </span>
      {' to play'}
    </p>
  </section>
}

You can see the result of the compiled code on the MDX playground.
MDX is part of the unified collective and built on many of its packages. Instead of doing manual parsing and text processing in a custom Python script, I recommend to use the official JavaScript utilities in Node.js.
For example:

Parse the HTML into hast using hast-util-from-html
Convert the hast to estree using hast-util-to-estree
Convert the estree to a string using estree-util-to-js
Once you get the hang of that, look into mdast and remark-mdx

